# How to separate model declaration from database connection?

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I'd like to declare models independent of a specific connection configuration.

A theoretical code would look like this:

```
const connection = require('bookshelf')(knex);

// Declare User model.
const User = require('bookshelf')
  .Model
  .extend({
    tableName: 'user'
});

// Fetch data for data model using a specific instance of Bookshelf.
User
  .use(connection)
  .fetchAll();
```

`.use` is a made-up method. I cannot find an equivalent method in [bookshelf.js](/questions/tagged/bookshelf.js) API.

The reason for wanting this level of separation is to enable isolated testing.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your issue is a configuration issue and not a bookshelf issue.  I think your best approach is to first use environment variables in node to store your database connection string.  The idea is to have specific config for different environments (dev, testing, stage, prod, etc) separated from the actual codebase.  There are plenty of ways to use environment variables in node, so I won't go into all of them.  A couple of good ones are [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) and [node-foreman](https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman).  We use node-foreman since we primarily run on heroku.  I have a .env file that contains configuration options that is NOT checked into git.  node-foreman supports json .env files, so mine would look something like this:

```
{
  "DATABASE_URL": "postgres://user:pass@host:port/schema",
  "LOG_LEVEL": "DEBUG"
}
```

It could include more than this, but you get the idea.  I would have multiple .env files for different environments (i.e. .env.dev, .env.test, .env.stage, etc).  Again, since I use node-foreman, I launch this with `nf start` which uses the .env file by default, but you can use the -e flag like so: `nf -e .env.test start`

You then access this configuration with `process.env` in your app.  You could then have db.js:

```
const dbOptions = {client: 'postgres', connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL};
const knex = require('knex')(dbOptions);
const bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
module.exports = {
    knex,
    bookshelf,
}
```

You'd then require this file where you need it in your models file.  So this might go in usermodel.js:

```
const bookshelf = require('./db').bookshelf;
const User = bookshelf
  .Model
  .extend({
    tableName: 'user'
});

module.exports = {
    User,
}
```

Then, in your app.js (or wherever you need to query users):

```
const User = require('./usermodel').User;
User.fetchAll();
```

So, once you have this set up, you simply start your app with a different config with `nf -e .env.whatever`

Comment: Having a dependency on a service makes these tests "service integration tests", not unit tests. This is solving a different issue.

Comment: You don't have to use dotenv or foreman to set up environment variables.  It just makes it easier.  Want to do it without the dependency?  Run the following:
DATABASE_URL="postgres://user:pass@host:port/schema" npm start